# Google Map API: Gdirections is Not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've got my map mostly rendering, but I keep getting an error in firebug stating that GDirections is not defined. This is the full error in firebug:

```
GDirections is not defined
initialize()?from=...ions%21 (line 39)
(?)()?from=...ions%21 (line 89)
F()jquery.min.js (line 19)
$(G=[function(), function()], K=function(), F=undefined)jquery.min.js (line 12)
F()jquery.min.js (line 19)
F()jquery.min.js (line 19)
[Break On This Error] gdir = new GDirections(map, document.getElementById("directions"));
```

It seems like somehow I am not referencing the API right.

Also, don't worry about the weird syntax of {{ addressable.lat }}. I am calling this from a Django template and that just passes in a value, in this case for the latitude.
This is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng({{ addressable.lat }}, {{ addressable.lon }});
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map,
      title:"{{ addressable.company }}"});

      gdir = new GDirections(map, document.getElementById("directions"));
      GEvent.addListener(gdir, "load", onGDirectionsLoad);
      GEvent.addListener(gdir, "error", handleErrors);

      setDirections("Pittsburgh, PA", "{{ addressable.address}}", "en_US");
  }

      function setDirections(fromAddress, toAddress, locale) {
        gdir.load("from: " + fromAddress + " to: " + toAddress,
                  { "locale": locale });
      }

      function handleErrors(){
         if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS)
           alert("No corresponding geographic location could be found for one of the specified addresses. This may be due to the fact that the address is relatively new, or it may be incorrect.\nError code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);
         else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_SERVER_ERROR)
           alert("A geocoding or directions request could not be successfully processed, yet the exact reason for the failure is not known.\n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);

         else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_MISSING_QUERY)
           alert("The HTTP q parameter was either missing or had no value. For geocoder requests, this means that an empty address was specified as input. For directions requests, this means that no query was specified in the input.\n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);

         else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_BAD_KEY)
           alert("The given key is either invalid or does not match the domain for which it was given. \n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);

         else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_BAD_REQUEST)
           alert("A directions request could not be successfully parsed.\n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);

         else alert("An unknown error occurred.");

       }

      function onGDirectionsLoad(){
        // Use this function to access information about the latest load()
        // results.
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDirections is part of API 2, but the rest of your code is in API 3 syntax.  You should be using the [DirectionsService](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsService) instead.  Also you've got references to GEvent as well which won't work either.